# Silverlight/WCF application is suddenly transferring extremely slowly

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, iis

I have a Silverlight 4 application that works a lot with a WCF service. The application has normally ran fine, with fast response times for even some hefty queries. Recently however, it's gotten quite slow, and I'm having a hard time troubleshooting why.

My database is hosted on a remote server. The application is hosted on the same server. Here's what I've noted:

1. When I run the application locally, using the ASP.NET as my server instead of IIS, and I hit the website via localhost, which hits the remote database, speeds are fast.
2. When I run the application locally, but use the remote WCF service rather than the local service, things are slow.
3. When I run the application over the web, (i.e. the remote application which is, again, on the same server as the database, so they're local to one another) the application is slow. This is pretty much what the production environment is...
4. When I log on to the server, and hit the the website from within the server, things are fast.
5. The queries to the database are fast. Manually running the queries on the database themselves, yields the results in a split second.
6. Using the WCFTestClient and hitting the remote WCF service is also really fast, and has virtually immediate turn around.

Lastly, when I'm using the expected setup of my local machine hitting the website over the web, which hits the database, etc:

1. Not all queries react the same way. Some of the heavier queries which result in large data sets actually have a quick response time. Some of the light queries - straight SELECT statements with no JOINS, that generate only a kilobyte of data, takes a lot longer...about 30 seconds. There are a few queries that are sometimes fast, sometimes slow, but the ones that are always slow are the worst.

About the server:

The server is a dedicated server, I've monitored the CPU and it's not being taxed by anything. I'm hosting with IIS 7, on Win Server 2K8, and Sql Server 2K8. The only thing that's changed in the past few weeks have been some Windows updates, and I've been told by one person that they made some Firewall changes - that's my current theory on the cause, but I don't know what else to try at this point, or how to show that it is the firewall..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddler. Fiddler was the answer (as it usually turns out to be.)

If you've experienced similar issues, hopefully what I've learned can be of help.

Here's what I saw:

First, when using both the Chrome/IE Profiler, it became clear that the Request itself was causing the lag, while the Response was quite quick.

This lead me down two paths of possibilities: Either the server was causing lag in the requests due to some specific configuration that I wouldn't see when running via localhost, or there was something wrong with the request itself.

After using Fiddler to get a full view  of the request, it became apparent that it was the request I was sending. One of the objects I was passing as a parameter to my WCF service had a property that, when serialized, amounted to about 1 megabyte's worth of data - and that was with gzip enabled. Initially this object was a rather small object, but as the application grew, so did this particular object, resulting in the sudden slow down.

The reason why it happened for certain calls and not others was purely determined by whichever call had this object as a parameter.

The reason why it happens when going over the web, vs. going through the localhost is that over the web, you inevitably face your provider's Upload limit, as well as a number of hops until you hit your server, vs. the direct connection from your localhost to your database.

**The lesson: Always transmit the least amount of information you can get away with.**

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find out the reasons according to what you described, I think you should start to profile your application by logging the database time, WCF request processing time etc.

Once you get the data, you can find the real reason. This is what we have been doing on our products.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, you're experiencing a combination of network latency and a less-than-optimal database design.  Your description of "small" queries taking longer than queries yielding large result sets is a classic indicator that you need to evaluate your query plans, and ensure that they are using the right indexes (you *are* using indexes, right?).

I suspect that sorting out your database issues will solve a great deal of the slowness you're experiencing; caching query results in memcached or something like it will solve most of the rest.

Generally, WCF is the last place I look for performance problems - every time I've gone that direction in the past, the trouble ended up being our code; WCF performs admirable well for its size.

I'm sorry that I can't be more specific, but performance questions are quite application-specific and we don't have much information here to go on.